# USB Keybord does not work

Tags: usb, keyboard, reset

I am running Ubuntu 20.4.keyboard is not responding. How do I reset the USB Ports. the ports located t the back of the computer re not working. keyboard. Please help.There re so many solutions which one should I follow?

I apologize for the delay. Its a Dell 3646 desktop.

The output of uname -a:

Linux seshagiri-Inspiron-3646 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:25:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have two external keyboards. and I have checked in all 4 USB ports. I was checking yesterday and found that some of the ports are not working.All the 4 failed yesterday at the same time.Both the keyboards are in perfectly working conditions.I just wanted to make sure there was bit delay in replying to your questions.

Here is the output:

seshagiri@seshagiri-Inspiron-3646:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:0036 Qualcomm Atheros Communications Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0157 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0461:4e22 Primax Electronics, Ltd USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:2111 Dell Computer Corp. Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yes  in Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: is this a lapptop? If so is an external keyboard working?  `uname -a` and `dmesg | grep grep intel-vbtn` any output? Please add all output's to your question.

Answer (score -2):

Settings -> Universal access -> Typing -> Screen Keyboard

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Maybe this will work?

Comment: That is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Would you please share the output of  lsusb